# Test nested variables in a while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable-substitution

I was trying to insert a nested variable as a while loop condition but I can't manage to expand it properly.

```
print_message() {
    timer=0
    timer_condition="$2"

    while [[ $timer_condition ]]; do
        sleep 1
        timer=$((timer+1))
    done
    echo "$1"
}

print_message 'Hello world, 5 seconds passed...' '$timer != "5"'
print_message 'Hello again, another 10 seconds passed...' '$timer != "10"'
```

As an example, I created a simple function print_message that accepts 2 arguments: $1 being the message to print and $2 being the condition I want the while loop to test, so that the function could be fed different conditions to display the messages.
However, the while loop is testing if $timer_condition itself is true, instead of testing its content. Is there a way to make it work like this?

```
while [[ $timer != "5" ]]; do
```

Thank you

Comment: Agree, not "nested variables". More like an anonymous or lambda function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval`:

> eval: eval [arg ...]
>
> Execute arguments as a shell command.
>
> Combine ARGs into a single string, use the result as input to the
>   shell, and execute the resulting commands.
>
> Exit Status: Returns exit status of command or success if command is
>   null.

A contrived example just to illustrate:

```
foo=bar
expr='[[ $foo == bar ]]'
if eval "$expr"; then
  echo 'foo is equal to "bar"'
fi
```

For your script pass `'[[ $timer != 5 ]]'` as your param and use

```
while eval "$timer_condition"; do
```

Be advised, though, that `eval` [should be used with caution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead) as it is easy to exploit if you're not careful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it fully works. However @fpmurphy1 provided a nice alternative which apparently doesn't pose the problems of `eval`. Both answers work in the scenario I provided, but yours was able to parse a more complex condition, ie: `[[ $(iwconfig wlan0 | grep "ESSID:off") ]]`. Would it be possible to use @fpmurphy1 method to test such conditions? From your answer I assume it would be better to avoid the `eval` if possible.

Comment: The other answer is the better answer _when it is applicable_ but it is applicable only for arithmetic evaluation. Within the double parens you can have integer arithmetic, logical, and bitwise operators (see the Arithmetic Evaluation section of `man bash`). If this doesn't apply to you you can often use `eval` safely if careful. You'll have to read up on it and decide what u want to do. (If only you are using/accessing the script then it's not too much of a concern.) Here's a nice site (the page has examples of "good" `eval` use): http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: Wish I knew why someone downvoted this. Did I make an error? Or do you just take 'eval is evil' literally?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing what you want to do:

```
print_message() {
    timer=0
    timer_condition="$2"

    while (( $timer_condition ))
    do
        sleep 1
        (( timer += 1 ))
    done
    echo "$1"
}

print_message 'Hello world, 5 seconds passed...' 'timer != 5'
print_message 'Hello again, another 10 seconds passed...' 'timer != 10'
```

~

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked perfectly. Apparently, compared to @b-layer alternative which involves the use of `eval` , this would be a simpler and more secure approach. However, using @b-layer method I was able to pass a different condition, ie: `$(iwconfig wlan0 | grep "ESSID:off")` to print the message "Wifi is connected" in case the condition verifies. Is it possible to parse it using your method?

Comment: @Radvansky, you typically will need to use `eval` in this case. See my example

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you wish the passed condition to be `ls -1 | grep demo` where `demo` is an existing file, here is a code snippet that works:

```
print_message() {
    condition="$2"

    if eval "$condition" > /dev/null
    then
        echo "$1"
    fi
}

print_message 'Found' 'ls -1 | grep demo'
```

Comment: Wish I knew why someone downvoted this.  Did I make an error?  Another 'eval is evil' believer?

Comment: I think someone downvote because of `eval` already mentioned in other answer before you posted.